# apply with ifelse statement and is.na does not 'sum' but outputs matrix - where is my logical mistake?

Tags: r, function, sum, integer, apply

probably a stupid question but I clearly can't see it and would appreciate your help.

Here is a fictional dataset:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c(101, 202, 303, 404),
                  var1 = c(1, NA, 0, 1),
                  var2 = c(NA, NA, 0, 1))
```

now I need to create a variable that sums the values up, per subject. The following works but ignores when var1 and var2 are NA:

```
try1 <- apply(dat[,c(2:3)], MARGIN=1, function(x) {sum(x==1, na.rm=TRUE)})
```

I would like the script to write NA if both var1 and var2 are NA, but if one of the two variables has an actual value, I'd like the script to treat the NA as 0. I have tried this:

```
check1 <- apply(dat[,2:3], MARGIN=1, function(x) 
{ifelse(x== is.na(dat$var1) & is.na(dat$var2), NA, {sum(x==1, na.rm=TRUE)})})
```

This, however, produces a 4x4 matrix (int[1:4,1:4]). The real dataset has hundreds of observations so that just became a mess...Does anybody see where I go wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version:

```
apply(dat[,2:3], MARGIN=1, function(x) 
  {
    if(all(is.na(x))) {
      NA
    } else {
      sum(x==1, na.rm=TRUE)
    }
  }
)
#[1]  1 NA  0  2
```

Issues with yours:

- Inside your `function(x)`, `x` is the `var1` and `var2` values for a particular row. You don't want to go back and reference `dat$var1` and `dat$var2`, which is the whole column! Just use `x`.
- `x== is.na(dat$var1) & is.na(dat$var2)` is strange. It's trying to check whether `x` is the same as `is.na(dat$var1)`?
- For a given row, we want to check whether all the values are `NA`. `ifelse` is vectorized and will return a vector - but we don't want a vector, we want a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` indicating whether all values are `NA`. So we use `all(is.na())`. And `if()` instead of `ifelse`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution and detailed explanation, now it's clear =)!